# How to add custom keys crashlytics in Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

I am new with crashlytics, I don't understand how to add custom keys to Android project. i visit cashlytics help center but i didn't understand well
Please help me how to add custom keys in project in simple way.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install crashlytics

[image]

select your project by clicking the crashlytics icon and choose your project to include crashlytics jar and it will automatically add the key in your manifest file.

[image]